# write the file and download the file same as of attachments

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

i have a requirement where i get byte array (byte[]) data from database, i need to save this data in a file and allow the user to save where ever he want to save, same as downloading the attachments.The file name and extension also i'm retrieving from database. I'm using java,spring-mvc for this.
Below is the code:

spring controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/getFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView getFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

             ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
             //logic to get the data from database

           byte[] documentData =  document.getDOCUMENTData();

               String documentName =  document.getDOCUMENTTITLE();

        String documentExt = document.getDocumentExtension();

}
```

Please suggest, i know that using java.io.*, i can write the byte[] data in file and give file name and extension by taking the values declared above, but how can i allow users when clicked on "download file" icon to write the data and save that file where ever he wants same as downloading the attachment.Please suggest. Once user clicks on download file icon control comes to above controller.Thanks.

--EDIT--
 Modified code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView getFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

             ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
             //logic to get the data from database

           byte[] documentData =  document.getDOCUMENTData();

               String documentName =  document.getDOCUMENTTITLE();

        String documentExt = document.getDocumentExtension();
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+userDoc.getDOCUMENT_TITLE());  
        long l =  userDoc.getDOCUMENT_SIZE();
        int size = (int)l;
        response.setContentLength(size);  
       response.getWriter().write("hello");//i need to write byte[] but for test i kept string.

}
```

I want user to see save window so that he can save where ever he want same as downloading the attachments from mail.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a code I'm usign for the same request

**HTML page:**

```html
<h:commandButton value="Click Here to Download" action="#{reportBean.download}" />
```

**BEAN:**

```java
public void download(){
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();  

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+file.getName());  
    response.setContentLength((int) file.length());  
    ServletOutputStream out = null;  
    try {  
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);  
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
        out = response.getOutputStream();  
        int i = 0;  
        while ((i = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {  
            out.write(buffer);  
            out.flush();  
        }  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getResponseComplete();
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException err) {  
        err.printStackTrace();  
    } finally {  
        try {  
            if (out != null) {  
                out.close();  
            }  
        } catch (IOException err) {  
            err.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    } 
}
```

Just make sure you have a File object named file

Answer (score -1):

You have two options to achieve this:

One is to write the file in your server's local filesystem in an internet accesible folder. You can configure which of your server's local folders are accesible from internet in your Apache/IIS serttings. Then you update your HTML so your "download file" link points to that file through an URL.

The other option is, like @an3sarmiento did, to return the file as a byte[] stream to the browser. For this option to work, you have to send, along with the file content, a response header in which you tell the browser you are returning a downloadable file as a stream. You do that with the line:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+[your file name]);
response.setContentLength([your file's length or bytes count]);
response.getWriter.write([your file's content as byte array]);
```

In the line above I assume you are working with Java Servlets and you have an `HttpServletResponse` variable named `reponse`, which you will respond to the browser's HTTP POST or GET request.

Comment: @RoRoberto Linares , i tried as you mentioned but could not able to save the file, not sure do i need to add anything else. Please have a look of the code posted above.